# upload file to server in a particular path

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

In Flex i want to upload a particular file to server form local system.how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** upload a file without using `FileReference.browse()` followed by an `upload()`. If it was possible, that would mean that a webpage can read any file from the user's machine without his knowledge or consent.

**Can you even imagine the consequences of that?**

Answer (score 1):

You can upload byteArrays though if you are sending some images or texts. http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=76422